# Angular 2: How to style host element of the component?

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, angular-components

I have component in Angular 2 called my-comp:

```
<my-comp></my-comp>
```

How does one style the host element of this component in Angular 2?

In Polymer, You would use ":host" selector. I tried it in Angular 2. But it doesn't work.

```
:host {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried using the component as selector:

```
my-comp {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Both approaches don't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the style is not applied? I've made a basic project and did exactly that and it worked. I've set `my-selector { color : red}` in my css and it works fine.

Comment: As of beta 7, the :host selector is working for me.

Comment: [Angular 2 Component styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)

Comment: @Pacane yes you are correct, it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 340, accepted):

There was a bug, but it was fixed in the meantime. `:host { }` works fine now.

Also supported are

- `:host(selector) { ... }` for `selector` to match attributes, classes, ... on the host element
- `:host-context(selector) { ... }` for `selector` to match elements, classes, ...on parent components
- *`selector /deep/ selector` (alias `selector >>> selector` doesn't work with SASS) for styles to match across element boundaries*

  - **UPDATE:** SASS is deprecating `/deep/`.
    Angular (TS and Dart) added `::ng-deep` as a replacement that's also compatible with SASS.
  - **UPDATE2:** `::slotted`
    `::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

See also [Load external css style into Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542143/load-external-css-style-into-angular-2-component/34963135#34963135)

`/deep/` and `>>>` are **not affected** by the same selector combinators that in Chrome which are deprecated.
Angular emulates (rewrites) them, and therefore doesn't depend on browsers supporting them.

This is also why `/deep/` and `>>>` don't work with `ViewEncapsulation.Native` which enables native shadow DOM and depends on browser support.

Comment: `@Component({selector: 'some-selector', template: 'xxx', styles: [':host { display: block; background-color: green; border: solid 1px red; }']}) export class SomeClass {}`

Comment: @OndraŽižka can you elaborate more? This is pure CSS, how can it be inconsistent with CSS and itself?

Comment: Unless I have missed some important shift in CSS, /deep/ and >>> are not CSS.

Comment: They are deprecated, but that doesm't matter. They are emulated by Angular (rewritten), therefore they only work with `ViewEncapsularion.Emulated` (default) but not with `Native`.

Comment: In Angular 2.4.7 I am able to get `:host { p { font-size: 80%; } }` to work in a ...component.css file. As soon as I try to use it with `styles: [:host { p { font-size: 80%; } }]` it no-longer works. Very strange.

Comment: You missed the quotes `styles: [":host { p { font-size: 80%; } }"]`

Comment: There is no difference in behavior between `styles` and `styleUrls`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to use this to style a component like :host(.mine) { color: green; } but it dosent seem to work , when i put this in the parent component ccs file

Comment: What is "this" that you put at the parent component? When you add `class="mine"` at the component itself, it should make the color of the component green where you add it at. If you add `class="mine"` at a parent or ancestor component, you need to use `:host-context(.mine) { color: green; `. If you add `:host(.mine) { color: green; }` at the parent component, then you need to add `class="mine"` at the parent component and the stile will also address the parent component only.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how can we access component variable inside host? If i want to decide background-color dynamically?  ':host { background-color: this.bgColor; }'

Comment: @PratapA.K What is "component variable inside host"?

Comment: In general, I have a variable inside my class "bgColorValue=red" and I want to set this value 
:host {background-color: this.bgColorValue}

Comment: @PratapA.K You can't access component variables from CSS. You can use `[style.backgroundColor]="bgColorValue"` on elements in your template or add `@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor')` before your `bgColorValue` variable

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the reply. having said that, is there a way to get css from the backend (100 classes css)? like in liferay? One of my component should provide a text box for the user to add css code and it should reflect in the component.

Comment: @PratapA.K sorry, don't think I can help you here. Perhaps better to create a new question with more details.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49530499/2742156

Answer (score 59):

I have found a solution how to style just the component element. I have not found any documentation how it works, but you can put attributes values into the component directive, under the 'host' property like this:

```
@Component({
    ...
    styles: [`
      :host {
        'style': 'display: table; height: 100%',
        'class': 'myClass'
      }`
})
export class MyComponent
{
    constructor() {}

    // Also you can use @HostBinding decorator
    @HostBinding('style.background-color') public color: string = 'lime';
    @HostBinding('class.highlighted') public highlighted: boolean = true;
}
```

UPDATE:
As Günter Zöchbauer mentioned, there was a bug, and now you can style the host element even in css file, like this:

```
:host{ ... }
```

Comment: I like this better than creating a dummy .root element, but I don't like that it sets these styles as inline (forcing a `!important` to override). There's got to be a better waayy :\

Comment: no, styling via `host{}` in a `stylesUrl` file does not work. needs `:host`.

Comment: how can we access component variable inside host? If i want to decide background-color dynamically?  ':host { background-color: this.bgColor; }'

Comment: @PratapA.K Hi, you can use HostBinding derorator. You example will be: `@HostBinding('style.background-color') private color = 'lime';`  Google will find you many examples and articles.

Comment: That helped a lot .Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3402). I think the bug will be resolved when [new template precompilation logic](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11r8IuS4xDyhVSEBp7fDYo7aiLYsLEXKs4lPd36umUGM/edit#heading=h.475vdcy2xzar) will be implemented. For now I think the best you can do is to wrap your template into `<div class="root">` and style this `div`:

```js
@Component({ ... })
@View({
  template: `
    <div class="root">
      <h2>Hello Angular2!</h2>
      <p>here is your template</p>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .root {
      background: blue;
    }
  `],
   ...
})
class SomeComponent {}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/47ncHQ3kUOWUTFo72CxB?p=preview)

Answer (score 11):

In your Component you can add .class to your host element if you would have some general styles that you want to apply.

```
export class MyComponent{
     @HostBinding('class') classes = 'classA classB';
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking to style child elements of a `:host` here is an example of how to use `::ng-deep`

`:host::ng-deep <child element>`

e.g `:host::ng-deep span { color: red; }`

As others said `/deep/` is deprecated

Comment: This seems to be most precise and subtle solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Try the :host > /deep/ :

Add the following to the parent.component.less file

```
:host {
    /deep/ app-child-component {
       //your child style
    }
}
```

Replace the app-child-component by your child selector

Comment: What if you want a stylesheet like bootstrap in there instead of a single style?

Comment: I do not recommend this anymore as /deep/ is deprecated.