# Using flexbox with angular 2 components

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, angular

I want to update visual side(grid, colors) of my angular 2 application. Old layout was build with bootstrap 4, which I don't really need anymore. I decided to go for plain css3, and build grid with flexbox. [I made a preview of this grid on codepen](http://codepen.io/Eggy/full/wKQrZE/).

However implementation in project is hard and I am now stuck. Let's consider an example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2';


@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `
    <aside class="col-4 main-aside"></aside>
    <section class="main-section center"></section>
  `
})
export class SomeComponent { }
```

If I bootstrap this component within, for example `.container` I may get this result:

```
<body>
  <!-- .container is flex parent -->
  <div class="container">
    <some-component>
      <!-- .main-aside and .main-section should be flex children -->
      <aside class="main-aside"></aside>
      <section class="main-section center"></section>
    </some-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see the flex chain parent -> child is broken because of component "selector" between them. I menaged to fix this by adding styles: `display: flex; width: 100%;` to component selector from chrome dev tools, however I don't know how to make this work from code perspective nor is it the best way to do so.

I would really appreciate any help, because I have no idea how to fix this with the exception of not using flexbox.

I am using angular 2.0.0-alpha.44

And yes, I am aware of angular's alpha state.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your `template` within `<div.container>`? This way the tree would look like `<some-component> <div class="container"><aside><section> </div> </some-component>`

Comment: @EricMartinez I can not do that, because <some-component> comes in fact from router so the full template looks like this:

<div class="container">
  <header class="main-header">
      <a [router-link]="['/' + routes.some.as]">Some component</a>
  </header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <1-- <some-component></some-component> -->
</div>

Comment: You can't specify a class on something in your HTML? Maybe it's possible just to add the class `.container` to the route handler component, and get rid of the additional `<div class="container">`. Either subclassing the route handler or just putting your `.container` in the inner template as @EricMartinez mentioned seem like totally valid ways to solve this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding styles to component. For example:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
}
```

`:host {}`  was the key.

Comment: I can't believe the timing here, I've been banging my head against this for days now. How did you figure this out? I wish I could upvote your whole life.

Comment: I found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component).

Comment: To be honest, I was wondering if anyone even sees this post or not. I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Was getting caught up on this for a while as well, thank you @Eggy

Comment: does it work with "plain" angular core or do I have to include something else?  I tried this but no success.  Static sketch of the page would do what I want but as soon as I turn Angular in, everything breaks.

Comment: It should work with bare angular application. Seems you have a problem with app itself not host styles. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Answer (score 1):

`:host` selector solves the problem but you end using it very often in many components.

I used instead the following global CSS:

```
.row > * {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular team released their own flex-layout package, so you don't need to write it by your self anylonger:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout