# Load external CSS into component

Tags: angular

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div></div>',
    styleUrls: [
        'http://example.com/external.css',
        'app/local.css'
    ]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

The `external.css` does not load.

Is there any way to load the external CSS in an Angular 2 Component?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Angular simply ignore the external one and not loaded.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

**View encapsulation**

To allow external styles to affect the content of components you can change view encapsulation (that's what prevents styles to "bleed into" components).

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    template: '<div></div>',
    styleUrls: [
        'http://example.com/external.css',
        'app/local.css'
    ], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, 
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

View encapsulation fulfills a purpose. The better way is to add styles directly to the component they should affect. 
`ViewEncapsulation` is set per component and may come handy in some situations.

**"shadow piercing"**

You can also use shadow piercing CSS combinator `::ng-deep` (`>>>` and `/deep/` are deprecated) to build selectors that cross component boundaries like

```ts
:host ::ng-deep .ng-invalid {
  border-bottom: solid 3px red;
}
```

- **update**
  `::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

which styles all tags with a class `ng-invalid` in the current component or any descendant with a red underline no matter if encapsulation is `None` or `Emulated`. It depends on browser support whether `/deep/` works with `Native` (as far as I know this is not supported by any browser anymore).

**Note**

The shadow piercing CSS combinators are similar to the ones from the shadow DOM spec where they are deprecated since quite a while.

With the **default** `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` Angulars own `/deep/` and `::shadow` implementation are used and they will work even when Chrome removes native support.

With `ViewEncapsulation.Native` Angular uses Chromes shadow DOM CSS combinators (only Chrome supported them at all anyway AFAIK). If Chrome finally removes them, then they won't work in Angular as well (again `ViewEncapsulation.Native` only).

**Global styles**

Styles added globally (`index.html`) don't consider component boundaries. Such styles are not rewritten by Angular2 and `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` doesn't apply to them. Only if `ViewEncapsulation.Native` is set and the browser has native shadow DOM support, then global styles can't bleed in.

See also this related issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5390

Comment: P.S.  When using encapsulation, a component selector is recommended to written into your Local.css to restrict the rules target.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua how can someone achieve that in terms of code?do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, should've been more clear. "This" refers to your solution of setting `encapsulation` to none. I believe I'm having the same issue as OP in my Ng2 app, and external css files declared in `styleUrls` (and being served from a CDN in my case) are still not being loaded and applied to the component. No errors/warnings. Same calls work just fine with Angular1/jQuery so its not a CORS issue. Fun times.

Comment: View encapsulation controls the behaviour of component styles bleeding *out* of the attached component and does not control external styles from bleeding *in* (they will always bleed in).

Comment: @Michael that's not true. Styles don't bleed in if `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` is set. Only styles added to your index.html (which are not rewritten by Angular) bleed in. If you add HTML dynamically using `[innerHTML]="..."` then the HTML is also not rewritten by Angular, styles from outside will bleed in.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, I should have clarified. By 'external' I mean external to the angular application (in index.html or equivalent) rather than  external to the component. I guess we were referring to different things.

Comment: @Michael there are some limitations though. The emulated encapsulation is not perfect. I guess you are relating to selectors like `a b { ... }` where `a` only applies to elements that match in the current element but `b` also matches elements in child elements. I think this will be fixed eventually.

Comment: @Michael the question is about styles added to `@Component({ styles: [...] })`. But you are definitely right about global styles. I added a section to my answer already.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , this is not working https://plnkr.co/edit/fGvBAimMnjffp4CJnqu2?p=preview

Comment: Link to official angular documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Answer (score 14):

**First of all** - The `styles`/`styleUrls` should only be used for any css rules that directly affect the style of the element from your template.

The reason your external.css doesn't get to applied to your component is because when you load these rules in external.css from `styleUrls` or `styles`, upon compiling, angular2 will append a unique component identifier like attribution selector to your original selectors.

For example, in your external.css, if there is a rule like `div.container { /*some rules*/ }`, it will become `div.container[_ngcontent-cds-2] { /*some rules*/ }`. So no matter how hard your try to force your rules become priority rules e.g. add `!important` tag, it is not going to work -- all selectors in your external.css have been restricted down one level to attribute selector, only the component element carries the same attribute. This is how angular2 restrict the styles to only current component.

#### Of course there is always a workaround.

Here is my solution -- I will add a external resource service, for all the js script, it will be using `SystemJS` to load either AMD or Globally, for all the css files, it will be using plain javascript to create a `<link>` element and append it to `<head>` element.

Here is a piece of my code for you consideration:

```js
loadCSS(url) {
  // Create link
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = url;
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
  
  let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  let links = head.getElementsByTagName('link');
  let style = head.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
  
  // Check if the same style sheet has been loaded already.
  let isLoaded = false;  
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var node = links[i];
    if (node.href.indexOf(link.href) > -1) {
      isLoaded = true;
    }
  }
  if (isLoaded) return;
  head.insertBefore(link, style);
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing this in *script you can just paste the `<link>` element into the `component.template html`. 
But in this case the css **bleeds out** of the component into the remaining app.

Comment: love this solution!

Answer (score 7):

This could be late, hope this helps someone else. To use ViewEncapsulation, just use
 `import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 1):

Better approach is already posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265072/5219412

You only have to add this in your component's declaration :

```
@Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

As specified in the angular documentation : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not good way. As commented above, a component should not handle global styles, not even with ViewEncapsulation.None. If component must affect anything outside of itself the service must be used. The reason is that we get a mess and conflicts if now we would have multiple CSS declarations on the same element

Answer (score -1):

Lots of complicated answers here but I've always found that if I'm wanting to create some styling that affects more than one component it's in effect a global style, hence I add it to styles.css.  This css file is special as it doesn't use the style encapsulation so affects every component.

This conceptually seems ok to me, just you have to use this sparingly else styles.css gets too big.

Rich

Comment: You're not actually answering the question, just saying "don't do it this way, do it another way". The user clearly wants to load an external CSS.