# Angular2 innerHtml removes styling

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am using innerHtml and set the html in my cms the response seems okay and if I print it like this`: {{ poi.content }}`

it gives me the right content back :
`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td style="vertical-align: top;">Tes11t</td>
       <td style="width: 2px;">&nbsp;</td>
       <td style="width: 1px;"><img alt="midgetgolf-sport-faciliteiten-vakantiepark-2.jpg" src="http://beeksebergen.dev/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/full_size/midgetgolf-sport-faciliteiten-vakantiepark-2.jpg" style="height: 67px; width: 100px;" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

`

But when I use `[innerHtml]="poi.content"` it gives me this html back:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tes11t</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img alt="midgetgolf-sport-faciliteiten-vakantiepark-2.jpg" src="http://beeksebergen.dev/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/full_size/midgetgolf-sport-faciliteiten-vakantiepark-2.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anybody know why it is stripping my styling when I use `[innerHtml]`

Comment: This looks like pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Angular2 sanitizes dynamically added HTML, styles, ...

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
    
  transform(html: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

```
[innerHtml]="poi.content | safeHtml"
```

See

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html
- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)
  for more details.

Comment: unhandled promise rejection: `EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for Safe: (?).
platform-browser.umd.js:2347 EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for Safe: (?).BrowserDomAdapter.logError `

also can't find name DomSanitizer

Comment: Do I have to import import DomSanitizer?

Comment: Yes, you have to import every type you use. You also need to add `Safe` to `declarations` in `NgModule`. If `DomSanitizer` doesn't work, try changing it to `Sanitizer`. I have seen it mentioned that this worked instead.

Comment: like this 
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';? or is it DomSanitizer? Because DomSanitizer isnt recognisble

Comment: `DomSanitizationService` is an old RC.x name. In final it's `DomSanitizer` or `Sanitizer`.

Comment: Thanks it is working I have to update my angular because in my case I use `DomSanitizationService`

Comment: That was super awesome solution. Make a pipe and use it anywhere.

Comment: I am using your solution but it is giving me error that "The pipe 'safeHtml' could not be found". 
How can I solved that ?
@GünterZöchbauer

Comment: my code
`import { Component,Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-article',
  templateUrl: 'news-article.html'
})
export class Article  {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}
   transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}`

Comment: It is mean't like "I (the developer) assure you (Angular) that I know what I'm doing and confirm thatbthe content is safe." It just adds a marker for Angular to know it should not meddle with the content. I don't claim this is the best possible name ;-) Suggestions welcome.