# Angular 2 striping off inline css styling

Tags: angular2-template, property-binding

I have a html content generated from my web api. This is passed on as json data to angular 2. I am using property binding to "inject" this content into a view. The process goes through successfully but angular 2 strips off all css styling

This how I am doing the binding

```
<div class="ReportViewerContent">
                <span [innerHTML]="reportData.Content"></span>
            </div>
```

This is what I am expecting (or some thing similar) per the sample application I am following which is not an agular app by the way
[image]

and in my application this what I am getting
[image]

How do I get angular 2 to ignore the inline styles that come along with the generated html string?

Comment: Looks like this question is already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794588/angular2-innerhtml-removes-styling?rq=1][1]

Comment: Ah!!! Thanks alot !!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 innerHtml removes styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794588/angular2-innerhtml-removes-styling)