# Importing external html using Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

i'm working on designing Angular Universal project and i want to get some stand alone html into my component and use it as view so that user will be able to edit template without dev efforts.

In just Angular 2+ it's possible to get external template in this way:
[Angular4 Load external html page in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659860/angular4-load-external-html-page-in-a-div?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Will it be possible to implement similar thing using Angular Universal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do exactly the same thing. Angular universal executes ajax calls and wait for components to be rendered before executing.

Like mentionned in the link you provided, you may need to use DomSanitizer if the html contains css