# Embed HTML file into Angular div

Tags: angular

I am trying to embed a Hosted HTML page in my angular app. However the div is coming back blank. I followed this article and modified the code for angular 7 to no avail [Angular4 Load external html page in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659860/angular4-load-external-html-page-in-a-div)

I console log out the result but it shows empty

My code is a as follows

```
  template: any = '';
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
      http.get('http://www.google.com').map((html: any) => this.template = html);
      console.log(this.template);
  }


  <div [innerHtml]="template"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `subscribe` to the observable in order to receive the data.

```
http.get('http://www.google.com').subscribe((html: any) => {
   this.template = html
   console.log(this.template);
});
```

Comment: I believe that is done automatically when using `map`. Probably he needs to change his syntax to use pipeable operators.

Comment: In order to fire up the observable (including map), we need to use the subscribe method

Comment: @enf0rcer I add the content inside the `susbcribe` function since i don't see why we need `map` operator in here. But if he is using it then, yes we need to use the pipeable operator

Comment: I get an error `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse` and message "Http failure during parsing for https://www.google.com/"

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka you are right it makes no sense in this context

Comment: @skydev i think what u need is iframe here `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>` instead of passing http request

Comment: ok thanks this works, I'll just now need to find a way to get values from the iframe

Comment: You'll have to use **[`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)** for that.