# What are the different ways you can show HTML page coming from an API call?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am getting one html page as response from an API call. I want to show it to the frontend side. What would be the best possible way I can do?

I have used `httpClient` request to get the data and `iframe` to show it and it works fine with me,but  I want to show the data in whole new HTML page.

```
  @ViewChild("iframe", { static: true }) iframe: ElementRef;
  //getting the iframe references from the html

  //From service
  getDataSummary() {
  return this._http.get(this.dataSummaryUrl, { responseType: "text" });
  }



  //Component ts file code
  onClickDataSummary() {
  this.fileUploadService.getDataSummary().subscribe(
    data => {
      let doc =
        this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
        this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(data);
      doc.close();
      this.dataSummaryLoading = false;
      this.dataSummaryDiv = true;
      this.showLoader = false;
    },
    error => {
      alert(` ${error.statusText} occurred!! Please check server side`);
      this.dataSummaryLoading = false;
      this.dataSummaryDiv = true;
      this.showLoader = false;
    }
  );
}
}
```

The HTML code would be like this -

```
 <mat-tab label="Data Summary">
  <mat-toolbar color="">
    <span>Data Summary</span>
    <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <span
      ><button
        mat-raised-button
        class=" mb-2"
        color="primary"
        (click)="onClickDataSummary()"
        *ngIf="!dataSummaryLoading"
      >
        Data Summary
      </button></span
    >
    <button
      class=" mb-2"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
      *ngIf="dataSummaryLoading"
    >
      <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm "></span>
      Loading
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <div
    class="example-container mat-elevation-z8"
    [class.hide]="!dataSummaryDiv"
  >
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" #iframe></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center m-5" [class.hide]="!showLoader">
    <app-loader></app-loader>
  </div>
</mat-tab>
```

Expected output would be to get the html page when click on a button. like here on clicking of `Data Summary` not in `iFrame`.

Thanks is advance for your time here.

Comment: do you want to open the html page in new window or want to display on same page

Comment: Well you can create a new Angular component that uses the html page as template. You can then route your API call to the new component using Angular routing. See this link: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @jitender what would be the options for both in new window and on same page?

Comment: @NadirLatif - I did not get your point. How I could store the html page coming from api call and store into an component template?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660076/5621827 to display in same window

Comment: @Souradip, If the html text is known, then you can set it as a html template for a component. But if the html page is coming from an API call, then you can set the innerHTML property of a element to the html text

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
let doc =
    this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument ||
    this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
```

to

```
let newWindow = window.open();

let doc = newWindow.document;
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. please do share other possible ways if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the HTML response should have the same header and footer and we just **[innerHTML]** it. But if you want to open it as a separate page then you have to use native javascript for it.

```
const html = '<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>';
const uri = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(html);
const newWindow = window.open(uri);
```

You can custom the window.open according to your preferences.

And if you want to use a different layout for this type of responses then you can check this out.

[multiple layouts for different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508804/9739044)