# Angular 2, DomSanitizer, bypassSecurityTrustHtml, SVG

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I've been using DomSanitizer with an SVG in an html string.

Previous to the current version of Angular, this worked just fine:

`this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);`

Now I am getting an object back called

```
SafeHtmlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "<svg> blah </svg>"}
changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity
```

Is there now a new way to access the output of the DomSanitizer? Should I be receiving it as SafeHTML type or something? What's the point in having bypassSecurityTrustHtml if it still filters html?

Any answers on a postcard? Please...

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @micronyks For some reasons it requires property binding `innerHTML="myData | pipeName" ` and does not work like this `innerHTML="useSanitizerFunc(myData)"`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/Qke2jktna55h40ubUl8o?p=preview**

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    console.log(this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value))
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="html | safeHtml">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  html: safeHtml;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.html = "<svg> blah </svg>";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have changed your svg to other svg to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. good idea about the pipe, I've set it up like that and works. Not actually doing anything functionally different but who's complaining? It works.

Comment: Who is complaining means?

Comment: It means I'm not complaining! Thanks for the help

Comment: If it solves the problem, accept answer so future reader will be able to get help.

Comment: Done. Thanks for help

Comment: This does not work when the SVG contains attributes that will be dynamically updated e.g. [attr.fill]="getColor()" instead of attr.fill="yellow"
e.g.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dCJEomWsXqOYG181iUus?p=preview

Comment: I am also having same issue, functions are not calling, just binding the html objects.

Comment: Does the sanitizers still works in angular 7? I am trying to load a script and it get shown but it does not get executed...

Comment: Because SVG can pose a security threat, it is highly recommended to sanitize the SVG beforehand. E.g. using https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Answer (score 1):

For that issue you can visit **[here](https://kknebulatech.blogspot.com/2021/07/angular-html-binding.html)**

We can add custom sanitized pipe and use globally. If your HTML is not sanitized properly then inner html ignore svg, third party url etc. so we can fix it like below:

**hero.component.html**:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString | sanitizedHtml"></div>
```

**hero.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-hero',
    templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
    htmlString: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.htmlString = `
        <div class="container">
            <header class="blog-header py-3">
            <div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="col-4 pt-1">
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">Subscribe</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <a class="blog-header-logo text-dark" href="#">Large</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mx-3"><circle cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="7.5"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15.8" y2="15.8"></line></svg>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </header>
        </div>`;
    }
}
```

**sanitized-html.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizedHtml'
})
export class SanitizedHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any): any {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Careful, with `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` you are not sanitizing your html but the name of your pipe is implying that you are! You should call it "UnsafeHtmlPipe" or run it through `DomSanitizer.sanitize()` if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

let html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<svg> blah </svg>");
```

More information: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#bypass-security-apis

Comment: This is what the OP stated that he is using in his question.

Comment: this worked for me in my current version. My issue wasn't what OP stated but I got what I came looking for. Many solutions suggested to use @Pipe and adding DOMSanitizer safeHTML but that's what I wanted to try last. With your solution, I was able to use DomSanitizer within my component file. Thanks Andrei.

Comment: Literally this is exactly what the OP says he is doing, and that it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done via object bracket notation:

```
let safeHtml = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
console.log(safeHtml["changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity");
```

Had to do this because `safeHtml.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` didn't work for me.