# How to implement spinner with loading controller in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, spinner, ionic3, loader

I want to implement spinner with loading controller in ionic3 . I have implemented simple loading controller . how to do it? thanks in advance.

My current loader

[image]

I want something like this

[image]

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#loading

Comment: I want something like as in "Show Custom" option , but unable to find source code. I have already implemented simple loader . https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/

Comment: What is the issue there? Can you show the `code`?

Comment: @Sampath there is no any issue , i just want to improve user experience. i have uploaded images of my current loader and what i want. i am unable to find what attributes to add here to get that. what to do within it-                     
                                                                                                                 let loader = this.loading.create({
      content: 'Loading Products...',
    });

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111306/1116320

Comment: that was helpful , but unable to implement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
presentLoadingCustom() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: `<img src="assets/img/gif.gif" />`,
      duration: 5000
    });

    loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed loading');
    });

    loading.present();
  }
```

inside image tag give some gif image and it works fine i have tested it

Output [image: imag]

Comment: do i have to put <spinner > tag in html and write some css for using it ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B09yT3sAy4UtbWU2X0ozM3pNZTg     here is how it looks.

Comment: @Niraj please check my updated answer and if you want any gif image https://giphy.com/gifs/mashable-3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40 save this gif image locally and place it in assets folder and everything works fine

Comment: thanks, its working when putting images -                                               
     let loader = this.loading.create({
    spinner: 'hide',
    content: `<img src="assets/img/spinner.png">`,
    duration: 5000
  });

Comment: i am glad that it helped you

Comment: add this option too dismissOnPageChange: true

Answer (score 3):

Ionic 2&3 has a built in service for blocking UI and giving visual feedback to users when the app is executing some time consuming activity on background such as loading data from a remote database .

You simply use the LoadingController which is available from ionic-angular module

So start by importing LadingController

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Then create a property and inject it on the class constructor

```
export class LoginPage {
loading: any;
constructor(public loadingController:LoadingController){...}
}
```

and create loading indicator in method from where requesting the data

```
login() {
    this.loading = this.loadingController.create({ content: "Logging in ,please wait..." });
    this.loading.present();
    this.errors = "";
    //api service call
    this.authService.postData(this.userData, 'api/account/login').then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      if (result != null) {
        this.loading.dismissAll();
        //console.log(result);
        this.common.setLocalData(DataKey.User.toString(), result);

        this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
      }
      else {
        this.loading.dismissAll();
        this.errors = "Nope, Try Again";
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.loading.dismissAll();
      this.errors = "Nope, Try Again";
      // Error log
    });
  }
```

When you are successfully logged in the method **dismissAll()** hides the loading indicator so you can continue interacting with your app normally.

Comment: do we need to use the create function inside every pages we make in ionic?
Can't we make a global provider and just make two function like show() and hide()?

Comment: Yes we create in global provider also.