# innerHTML not working in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I loop an observable that contains information about the content of my article but when I use innerHtml, I still have the HTML tags that appear.

```
<div *ngFor="let article of informationsArticle|async;">

      <p [innerHTML]="article.contenu_part1" *ngIf="article.contenu_part1"></p>

</div>
```

[image]

I do not understand why because it seems correct..

Does not work with DomSanitizer :

keep-html.pipe.ts :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

contenu-article.html :

```
<div *ngFor="let article of informationsArticle|async;">

      <p [innerHTML]="article.contenu_part1 | keepHtml" *ngIf="article.contenu_part1"></p>

</div>
```

I added EscapeHtmlPipe in "declarations" of app.module.ts file with the import.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857858/angular-2-domsanitizer-bypasssecuritytrusthtml-svg

Comment: I already tried and it does not work

Comment: Other proposition ?

Comment: Update your question with the code utilizing DomSanitizer so I can take a look.

Comment: My question is updated

Comment: I think I know where my problem comes from. I have a <p> tag and inside I have another <p> tag (my string) but when I replace my <p> tag by <div>, it's not work..

Comment: No idea to solve my problem ? :/