# Bind directives dynamically using Renderer2 in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I'm trying to get the following rendered on my HTML using Renderer2

```
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="valForm.controls['email'].hasError('required') && (valForm.controls['email'].dirty || valForm.controls['email'].touched)">This field is required</div>
```

Above is a required field validation for a textbox but the "div" needs to be rendered dynamically. I'm using below code at the moment.

```
 const validator_div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
 this.renderer.addClass(validator_div, 'text-danger');
 validator_div.innerHTML = "This field is required";

 this.renderer.setAttribute(validator_div, "*ngIf", "valForm.controls['formControlName'].hasError('required') && (valForm.controls['formControlName'].dirty || valForm.controls['formControlName'].touched)");
```

Code throws an error

> Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '*ngIf' is not a valid
>   attribute name.

Comment: look to this post maybe it can help you[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963469/assigning-angular-structural-directives-during-runtime)