# angular conditional html binding

Tags: angular

I need to conditionally add an extra html as a div content.
For now I did it this way:

before:

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells" class="cell"
    [innerHTML]="cell.dataWithHtml"
></div>
```

after:

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells" class="cell">
    <img *ngIf="cell.isSpecial" src="whatever"/>
    <div class="this_div_should_not_exist" [innerHTML]="cell.dataWithHtml"></div>
</div>
```

But this adds an extra div.

How this block can be rewritten without adding extra div?

Comment: how about using interpolation? {{cell.dataWithHtml}}

Comment: it will escape html characters

Comment: Possible duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857858/angular-2-domsanitizer-bypasssecuritytrusthtml-svg

Comment: It is not a question about escaping html. This is a question about adding extra conditional html to inner html, I think I can try to use a pipe, for adding extra html.

Comment: you can use `<span [innerHTML]=...></span>`

Comment: brilliant mind,, you just replaced div with span. I do not want to add ANY extra html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outerHTML` on the `div` you wish to disappear/replace - you can't use `ng-container`.

```html
<div class="this_div_should_not_exist" [outerHTML]="cell.dataWithHtml"></div>
```