# Angular fully escape in [innerHTML]

Tags: angular

I use `[innerHTML]` to add some content to a div `[innerHTML]="value"`.

When `value` contains HTML e.g. `some <i>text</i> foo bar` then the italic style will be rendered because it is treated as safe.

Is there a way that I can escape ALL of its html somehow?

E.g. i want the result to be `some <i>text</i> lorem`

**UPDATE**

Here is a more qualified example what I try to do

`<div [innerHTML] = value | highlight`

I also use a pipe called highlight which adds some HTML highlighting stuff, so `innerText` does not work for me. I really need to escape all HTML from `value` before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2, DomSanitizer, bypassSecurityTrustHtml, SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857858/angular-2-domsanitizer-bypasssecuritytrusthtml-svg)

Comment: render it as text `<div>{{value}}</div>`

Comment: use [innerText] instead)