# Angular 2 SVG not rendering

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I created a component to render SVG images that are within my app.

The are loaded dynamically as the however, my demo app just show a simpler version.

http://plnkr.co/edit/g2tZXeUAMJ5zESx2EHT0?p=info

i tried `<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>` and `<div> {{ data }} </div>`

The SVG is not being loaded though the call is correct. I spent sometime in gitter to find a solution but the closest i got was it it's being sanitzed.

The innerHTML i assume is being sanitzed and the interpolation is being ignored. It just shows the raw svg text.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular is sanitizing the content. To work around explicitly tell Angular that it can trust your HTML

import { Pipe, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';

You can use a reusable pipe or call `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html)` directly.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'bypassHtmlSanitizer' })
export class BypassHtmlSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
[innerHTML]="data | bypassHtmlSanitizer"
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ib0bhrwhQEKH7kLEQdyh?p=preview)

See also [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Comment: Thanks one more thing before you go. If i wanted to style the svg through that component how could it be done?

Comment: I guess you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling/36265072#36265072

Comment: In newer versions of Angular you have to use `DomSanitizer` instead of `Sanitizer` to use this

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add to Günter Zöchbauer's accepted answer, that in newer versions of Angular, we need to use `DomSanitizer` instead of `Sanitizer`, which can be imported using `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`.