# Inline styling in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am getting blocks of HTML codes from HTTP calls which **has inline styling** in it. I put the HTML blocks in a variable and insert it on my page with [innerHTML] but I cannot see the style reflected in the inserted HTML block. Does anyone have any suggestion how I can achieve this?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="html">
    <div [innerHtml]="html">
    </div>
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  html: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.html = "<span style=\"color:red;\">1234</span>";
  }
}
```

In the above example 1234 is not coming red.

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQJOFMKl9OwMRIJ38U8D?p=preview/)

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed. Perhaps a Plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling see your first comment (in that from within the component)

Comment: I asked you to create a question instead of a comment, because here you can add code ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added the plnkr now

Answer (score 6):

```
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    this.html = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<span style=\"color:red;\">1234</span>");
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hHeQio42HjCBaKRzaVjt?p=preview)

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html
- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code in plunker as shown below :

```
import {Component, NgModule,ElementRef,ViewChild} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="html">
    <div [innerHtml]="html" #value>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  html: string;

  @ViewChild("value") el : ElementRef

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.html = "1234";
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not accept this solution because this.html could be HTML code of a page which has 1000 divs and each div could have inline css. In that case this solution wont work.

Comment: Don't touch nativeElement directly, use Renderer2