# How to applay CSS .class from innerHTML

Tags: css, angular, innerhtml

I have pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
   name: 'spaning',
   pure: false
})
export class SpanPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
transform(value: string): string
    {
        return "<span class='mark'>xxx</div>"+value;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="movie.title| spaning"></div>
```

How to style .mark class in css? I want that **xxx** become red. I do not interested in workaround, class must be added in pipe, as above.

Answer is somehow related to 
[Angular 2 - innerHTML styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling), but I can't find solution by myself.

---

If I just add style to my component where I use this pipe:

```
.mark{
    color: red;
}
```

I get:

> "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)."

Comment: you're using a Pipe in a place where a Component would suit perfectly...

Comment: Yes, probably you have right. And probably I will end up using component here, now I want to try by my way.

Comment: why not just style it via css?

Comment: @fatman I edit my question to notify everyone why simple approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[innerHTML]` can not be used without **`DOMSanitizer provider`** or it will throw security error. You can use **`DOMSanitizer provider`** in your custom pipe to sanitize your HTML as shown below,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({
   name: 'spaning',
   pure: false
})
export class SpanPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: string,color:any): SafeHtml{
       return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<span class='mark' [ngStyle]="{'color':color}">xxx</div>"+value);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="movie.title| spaning :'red'"></div>
```

Comment: Congratulations, works in 100%. Just change types to SafeHtml, and import it.

Answer (score 2):

https://plnkr.co/edit/p0hsn57WT9FfO6E6lRjL?p=info <- plunkr

Turn the view encapsulation mode for your component to 'None' for the hard-coded class to be work in the component

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core'
```

in the decorator

```
selector: 'your-component',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

then sanitize the HTML in your pipe before returning it

```
export class SpanPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: string): any {
       return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<span class='mark'>xxx</div>"+value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Work in 100%, but have drawbacks with leaking css style out of component. Anyway problem solved, thanks for answer.

Comment: Its the only way  to apply a component class to injected HTML without using the renderer :P

Comment: Just make the styles very unique... class name -  mark0381832080dj1  :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Sorry for that.. When you're inserting new html tags you must use [DOMSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

I'm attaching plunker to show how to use it properly

https://plnkr.co/edit/vBnF9hPSpw46053FQ08G?p=preview

---

You can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle).

[Pipes transform](https://angular.io/api/core/PipeTransform) function get two parameters: 'value' and 'args':

```
export interface PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any;
}
```

So you can pass your pipe arguments. In this case I'm passing the string 'red' (Witch could easily be a variable..) and use it inside the transform function.

.html:

```
<div [innerHTML]="movie.title| spaning :'red'"></div>
```

.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
   name: 'spaning',
   pure: false
})
export class SpanPipe implements PipeTransform 
{
transform(value: string,color:any): string
    {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<span class='mark' style=color:"+color+">xxx "+value+"</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for you? I get "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)."