# Unable to apply styles to svg's in component css with Angular, only in global css file

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have a "Sidenav" component in which I use svg's as menu icons, but I'm unable to apply styles to those icons from within the component scss file, It works only from within the global scss file.

Since I deal with "svg", "polygon", "path" .... tags, it doesn't work in the component scss file.

Is there a way to make it work since I only use those svg's in my component ?

**Code example :**

```
<div id="sidenav-icon-section">
      <li class="bleu-icon">
          <a href="/">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64" xml:space="preserve" data-inject-url="http://localhost:4200/assets/images/menu_items/accueil.svg" _ngcontent-c1="">
                <polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="32,3 2,33 11,33 11,63 23,63 23,47 39,47   39,63 51,63 51,33 62,33 "></polygon>
                </svg>
            </a> 
        </li>
    </div>
```

This css code will work in my global scss file, but not in my component css file :

```
#sidenav-icon-section {

  .bleu-icon polygon {
    transition: .2s !important;
  }

  &:hover .bleu-icon polygon {
    stroke: #009999 !important;
  }
}
```

or even any css property like this :

```
svg {
dislay: none;
}
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code, ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @ccprog done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `...`,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
  ...
})
```

This will place your component's styling in your page's `head` tag.

Comment: This should come with a fine print text of "Will inadvertently apply styles to any matched selector within the application opposed to being encapsulated within the component". I think this is more of a hack. Kind of like using `::ng-deep`

Answer (score 3):

Please see this SO post:
[Angular 2 - innerHTML styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling)

which suggests prefacing the CSS selectors with

```
:host ::ng-deep.
```

i.e.

```
 :host ::ng-deep .bleu-icon polygon {
    transition: .2s !important;
  }
```

The linked SO post indicates that `::ng-deep` is a bit of a hack (supporting mwilson's comment above) and that `::ng-deep` is marked for depreciation. However, I haven't seen a proposed alternative, just lots of discussion that one is needed.

The other solution is to add the styles in javascript. I agree that this is just as awkward, because then why have SASS at all? But it works.