# Angular 7 - innerHTML - rendering HTML tags from DB

Tags: css, angular, angular7, encapsulation, sanitization

I am creating a documentation tool, where you have the possibility to write a document (in contenteditable elements), where you can insert diferent kind of boxes and so on with a formatted style ( classnames ).

It is saved to mongoDB on upload, but when I am rendering the documents from the DB by innerHTML, the styles are only rendered on the elements in case I have the css definition on the TAG, and not on a CLASS.

For example 
Works:

```
code {
 color: red;
}
```

Does not work:

```
.jcl-code {
 color: red;
}
```

I have the viewEncapsulation.None settled, and also made a safeHtml pipe to skip sanitizing.

```
<p class="card-body" innerHTML="doc[currentId].body | safeHtml">
```

Can you please give me some hints why it doesn't work with classes?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `:host ::ng-deep` to your class
so `:host ::ng-deep .jcl-code {...}` as the necessary classes are not added automatically to HTML added via `[innerHTML]`.

for more details and information about `::ng-deep` and it's usage check https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265072/606104