# How can I resolve "safeHtml pipe not working" in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have to make use of innerHtml directive but it ignores the styling of the elements so I created a custom `safeHtml` pipe to render the CSS of the element basically, I am injecting HTML elements to my dom using `innerHtml`. But the pip doesn't work.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SafeHtmlPipe } from './view/post.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ViewComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SafeHtmlPipe
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**post.pipe.ts**

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "safeHtml" })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

**view.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-view",
  templateUrl: "./view.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./view.component.scss"]
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  card = {
    title: `Title here`,
    shortDesc: `Short desc`,
    author: `Author`,
    thumbnail: `Thumbnail URL`,
    datePublished: `date`,
    content: `card content`
  };

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  showPostContent() {
    document.getElementById("postContent").innerHTML = this.card.content;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
    });
    // this.showPostContent();
  }
}
```

**view.component.html**

```html
<div [innerHtml]="card.content | safeHtml"></div>
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Comment: Are the styles for card content specified in parent component css or are these inline in the card content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a simple `ViewChild()`.

**HTML**:

```
<div #simpleDiv></div>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('simpleDiv', { static: true }) simple;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.simple.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'AAA';
  }
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7y9tba?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Be aware however that there are **very few legitimate reasons** to use innerHTML directly in angular. and whatever it is you're trying to achieve. can most likely be done in a safer more, 'angularish' way.

wherever I see innerHTML in a modern framework application, it almost always ends up being some **web developer** who tries to achieve something, in the tools he already knows, going around the framework, rather than learning how to do it properly using the framework.

Alas, I can be wrong.

Comment: The styling works only in inline mode but when a class is given (defined in the app.component.css also) it doesn't work. I want the defined class on the injected elements to work properly as same as the DOM manipulation in vanilla javascript. (In reference to the above stackblitz)

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper place your css in the `styles.css` file. not in the app component's

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper changed a bit the stackblitz from above: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa4gwf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @YogeshDeveloper can you post the solution

Comment: The problem is that the styles are not component scoped anymore. Did anyone found a proper working solution where the styles are working as usual within component scoping? (the css prefixing)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue that styles from this `innerHTML` will bleed out, see [Angular 2 - innerHTML styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling) and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7845