# Does the current version of the Angular-Slickgrid support the DomSanitization

Tags: angular, innerhtml, angular-slickgrid

Does the current version of the Angular-Slickgrid support the DomSanitization? If yes please help me to do it.

Requirement: From the API call I get the rich text as data, which has HTML elements in it. I need to display the rich text into the grid **as is** to have the formatting (e.g. **bold**, underline).

Here is the sample data that comes from the API:

```
name: \<strong>\<underline>John K Paul\</underline>\</strong>
```

Here is a similar ask from another person.
[How can I resolve "safeHtml pipe not working" in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039071/how-can-i-resolve-safehtml-pipe-not-working-in-angular-8)

Answer (score 0):

I had already replied to the same question you asked in GitHub [Discussion](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/discussions/838), below is the same answer to your question.

Angular-Slickgrid (Slickgrid-Universal) uses [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) internally, that is what you should use in a Custom Formatter, for example you can see it implemented in this [TreeFormatter](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/version2/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/formatters/treeFormatter.ts#L47) for example.

```
import * as DOMPurify_ from 'dompurify';
const DOMPurify = DOMPurify_; // patch to fix rollup to work
// ...
const sanitizedOutputValue = DOMPurify.sanitize(outputValue);
return sanitizedOutputValue;
```

It is recommended to use [Custom Formatter](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters#custom-formatter) instead of Angular Pipe (which would require [asyncPostRenderer](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters#using-angular-component-with-asyncpostrenderer) and are much slower (hence why it's not recommended, better stick with Custom Formatter).