# Insert snippet HTML from JSON and render it as HTML

Tags: html, angular, render, code-snippets

I have this code in my Template HTML

```
    <div *ngIf="alertOptions?.texts">
      <p *ngFor="let paragraph of alertOptions?.texts">
        {{ paragraph }}
      </p>
    </div>
```

The Texts in my JSON are like:

```
Please <b>Call us</b> <a href="tel:+5798643210"> 5798643210</a>.<br>Weekends Chat with us <a href="#">Chat</a>
```

I Know that I need to escape the quotes in my JSON!

```
"alertOptions":{
    "texts": [
      "Please <b>Call us</b> <a href=\"tel:+5798643210\"> 5798643210</a>.<br>Weekends Chat with us <a href=\"#\">Chat</a>"
    ]
}
```

But, I get[image]

How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Hello, in JS you don't need the escape quote if you use [template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling

Answer (score 2):

Please try `<div [innerHTML]="paragraph" > </div>`