# How to load external CSS in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, styles

I'm trying to use some external CSS for my component on "5 MIN QUICKSTART"

**This is what I've tried (following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34963135/3264998)):**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['https://example.com/themes/default/style.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

**Check the code on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e2xsPPRJ5lzvqiGgKw5V?p=preview)**

Styles do not apply on my component, also when checking "Sources" from "Developer tools", the images/fonts/ from the external CSS do not seem to get loaded.
Is there something that i'm missing?

Comment: which version of angular are you using ? try setting `moduleId : module.id` in your component

Comment: @candidJ I'm using RC5, i tried to add moduleId : module.id in the component, i have the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

`export function isStyleUrlResolvable(url: string): boolean {
  if (isBlank(url) || url.length === 0 || url[0] == '/') return false;
    var schemeMatch = RegExpWrapper.firstMatch(_urlWithSchemaRe, url);
    return isBlank(schemeMatch) || schemeMatch[1] == 'package' || schemeMatch[1] == 'asset';
}`

Seems that for url schemes, will return false.

The solutions was to use a local css file and just import the external css, like so:

`@import url("https://example.com/themes/default/style.css");`