# How to style ng-bootstrap components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply styles to the ngbTooltip component in my Angular 2 app. I apply the directive as:

```
<div [ngbTooltip]="tooltipText">
    Element text
</div>
```

But since Angular 2 applies style scoping, I can't directly style the `.tooltip` class in my component's template.

How can I give the tooltips *for this specific component* a custom styling?

EDIT:

I have a scss stylesheet that's attached to my component. My styles (simplified) are:

```
.license-circle {
    width: 10px;
    ... other styles
}

/deep/ .tooltip {
    &.in {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

But then my rendered styles look like:

```
<style>
.license-circle[_ngcontent-uvi-11] {
  width: 10px; }

.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1; }
</style>
```

Which makes me believe the tooltip styles are being un-encapsulated (instead of just *piercing* this component's children.

Note: I tried `:host >>> .tooltip` and it didn't work, so I ended up using `/deep/`.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542143/load-external-css-style-into-angular-2-component/34963135#34963135 might help (shadow piercing)

Comment: It worked, thanks! But I'm worried these piercing styles will be global.

Comment: What do you mean with "global"? If you start the selector with `:host ...` then they are only applied to this component and it's children.

Comment: My style doesn't seem to be scoped for that element
```css
[_nghost-epe-11] {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center; }

.license-circle[_ngcontent-epe-11] {
  ....
}

  .tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1; }

  .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you tried?

Comment: arg, I'll updating my question. give me 5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the selectors should start with `:host`

```
:host .license-circle {
    width: 10px;
    ... other styles
}

:host /deep/ .tooltip {
    &.in {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought `:host >>>` == `/deep/` and didn't realize I was missing `:host` :)

Comment: I see. Yes `>>>` and `/deep/` are interchangeable. It was mentioned somewhere that one of them works better in SASS but I don't remember which :-/

Comment: For the record, I'm using sass and `/deep/` :)

Comment: You chose well ;-) https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7108#issuecomment-246386451

Answer (score 4):

For angular version 8.3, ::ng-deep is recommended

```
::host .license-circle {
  width: 10px;
  ... other styles
}

:host ::ng-deep .tooltip {
  &.in {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

> One thing that we need to remember is that ::ng-deep, /deep/ & >>> have been deprecated in angular 9. So, finding some other long term solution would be a good thing to do at this point. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) for more.