# primeNG - implement css style to dataTable

Tags: html, css, primeng

I want to change the colors of the DataTable but I cant implement my custom css to it. Please help me understand how to do it. I ve read the documentation at PrimeNG website.

I did change the thead style using :

```
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-thead > tr > th {background: red;}
```

but i want to know how to use [styleClass] to implement my custom colors to it.

Comment: can you add your HTML and full CSS please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Best way to override the style of primeng components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131174/what-is-best-way-to-override-the-style-of-primeng-components)

Answer (score 1):

Mark `!important` tag to your custom styles. May be it will works for you.

```
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-thead > tr > th {
   background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below css

```
.ui-state-default.ui-unselectable-text {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```