# Prime NG - Auto Complete CSS style applying

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

I would like to understand how to apply CSS for the existing PrimeNG autoComplete component.

The change I am looking for is, the input text color should be white.

HTML file (**top-bar.component.html**)

```
<p-autoComplete styleClass="myclass" [(ngModel)]="brand" [suggestions]="filteredBrands" (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="20" [minLength]="1"
      placeholder="Search" [dropdown]="true" (keyup.enter)="populateResults($event)">
    </p-autoComplete>
```

CSS class (**top-bar.component.css**)

```
.myclass .ui-autocomplete .ui-autocomplete-input {
  color: white;
}
```

Component class (**top-bar.component.ts**)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
})
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131174/what-is-best-way-to-override-the-style-of-primeng-components/43552505#43552505)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `[inputStyle]="{'color': 'white'}"`. If multiple styles need to be applied, `inputStyleClass` is even more convenient way. Refer to this docs https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6.1.6/#/autocomplete

Answer (score 6):

I could fix it from the @Aravind suggest link. Removed the styleClass from  and modifed the css with **:host >>>**.

If the css file is of type scss then use **::ng-deep**

HTML file (**top-bar.component.html**)

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="brand" [suggestions]="filteredBrands" (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="20" [minLength]="1"
      placeholder="Search" [dropdown]="true" (keyup.enter)="populateResults($event)">
    </p-autoComplete>
```

CSS class (**top-bar.component.css**)

```
:host >>> .ui-autocomplete .ui-autocomplete-input {
  color: white;
}
```

**IF SCSS class** (**top-bar.component.scss**)

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-autocomplete .ui-autocomplete-input {
  color: white;
}
```

Component class (**top-bar.component.ts**)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this CSS :

```
.ui-autocomplete>.ui-inputtext {
  color: white;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9bbRYYyf0XqUccjbsevv?p=preview)

Comment: The changes are done in styles.css but I am looking to change in the component associated styling file (top-bar.component.css)

Comment: Placing this CSS in `top-bar.component.css` should work for you. If not, can you create a Plunker please ?

Comment: I just posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Prime ng Autocomplete custom style**

```
<p-autoComplete 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedMenu" 
      [suggestions]="filteredMenus" 
      (completeMethod)="filterMenu($event)"
      field="value_en" 
      [minLength]="3"
      (onSelect)="itemSelectEvent($event)"
      placeholder="Search Menu ..."
      size="50"
      [style]="{
        display: 'inline-flex',
        height: '34px'
      }"
      >
    </p-autoComplete>
```

size="50" indicates the input width size