# PrimeNG Calendar - Override the default style

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

Using angular, I am using p-calendar in a component and created a CSS class that is called from my component. No matter what I do I am unable to override the style.

**CSS**

```
.ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button {
    height: 34px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    width: 900em;
    border-left: 0 none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3"
                                     [ngClass]="{
                                     'has-error':(ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').touched || ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').dirty ) &&
                                     !ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').valid
                                     }">
                                    <label for="effectiveDtId" class="control-label">Effective Date</label><br />

                                    <p-calendar formControlName="effectiveDt" id="effectiveDtId" [showIcon]="true"
                                                 inputStyleClass="form-control " 
                                                 class="ui-calendar ui-calendar-button"
                                                 [style]="{'width': '100%','display': 'inline-flex','height':'34px'}"  ></p-calendar>

                                </div>
```

****************************************************UPDATE****************************************

I changed my SCSS File to

```
::ng-deep .only-style-this .ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button { 
height: 34px !important; 
border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3 only-style-this"
                                 [ngClass]="{
                                 'has-error':(ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').touched || ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').dirty ) &&
                                 !ersaForm.get('effectiveDt').valid
                                 }">
                                <label for="effectiveDtId" class="control-label">Effective Date</label><br />

                                <p-calendar formControlName="effectiveDt" id="effectiveDtId" [showIcon]="true"
                                             inputStyleClass="form-control" 

                                             styleCalss=".ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button"
                                             [style]="{'width': '100%','display': 'inline-flex','height':'34px'}"  ></p-calendar>

                            </div>
```

**warning**

Validation (CSS 3.0): "::ng-deep" is not a valid pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tweak a child component's css, it breaks encapsulation. This will work but is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

```
::ng-deep .ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button {
    height: 34px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    width: 900em;
    border-left: 0 none;
}
```

This is essentially the same as adding it to your global stylesheet. However, the global styles will be applied only when the component has loaded for the first time, making it uber crappy. For safety, you can wrap your component in an "only-style-this" class and do:

```
::ng-deep .only-style-this .ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, prime-ng usually allows you to pass styles in with most its components.

If you look at the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) you will find that there is a style property you can use. There are also other properties you might want to play with like inputStyle.

Comment: updated my code above....still not working ..also unable o pass the style in inputStyle

Comment: you need this <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-md-3 only-style-this"

Comment: it seems it does not allow ::ng:deep in css, change the file extension from css to scss and the stylesUrl in the component to scss too

Comment: changed from css to scss and still the same issue..even I am getting the same warning

Comment: any other ideas!

Comment: I am guessing .ui-calendar .ui-calendar-button refers to a button nested inside .ui-calendar ... the only other idea would be to add !important to all your css rules

Comment: when say "adding important to my css" do you have an example

Comment: height: 34px !important;   border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;  etcetera

Comment: also tried solutions from (nothing worked) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131174/what-is-best-way-to-override-the-style-of-primeng-components

Comment: OMG I had (styleCalss) instaed of (styleClass) mistyped "CLASS"..all works now

Answer (score 0):

I  use  prime ng ver 12.xx
override  this  ok  for me on file style.css (Angular cli

```
.p-datepicker table td{ padding: 0px; }
.p-datepicker table td > span {  height: 45px;width: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the following answer https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=53756 just put your style as list item in the array of styles in the file angular.json

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
          "../node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

then you can use your css freely