# span within a tag with same space

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanna put a span within an a tag that covers all the same space(I mean the span with same space(width and height) of  tag)

```
<a class="a-tab">
   <span class="fa fa-fw fa-plus">
</a>

.a-tab{
     float: none;
     display: inline-block;
     color: #333333;
     padding: 0.571em 1em;
     font-weight: 700;
}

.fa-fw{
    width: 1.28571429em;
    text-align: center;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

 }
```

so the problem is that I can't change the  tag because it's from a lib and the fa plus icon. The only thing I can change is the `<span>`, maybe with a `<div>`. But it seems doesn't work. I tried to put a width: 100% and height: 100% but still not works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *covers all the same space* --> what space?

Comment: I mean the span with same space(width and height) of <a> tag

Comment: Your span should be the one giving its size to your a tag. If you want your link to wrap around your span you should first remove the padding from the link.

Comment: I can't touch the css of <a> it's from a lib

Comment: Sure you can...you just add another rule or class...why do you think you can't? Libraries are just helpers you can adapt them as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these styles:

```
a.a-tab {
    position: relative !important;
}

a.a-tab span {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: `The only thing I can change is the , maybe with a ` - didn't you tell, you can?

Comment: The library is known as FontAwesome. I've used it on several projects. And there was no problems with styling.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry I don't know why it was not correct. However it's part of PrimeNG component.

Comment: If you use Angular, then components have encapsulated styles. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131174/what-is-best-way-to-override-the-style-of-primeng-components

Comment: yes I can use ::ng-deep.. the problem with padding: 0 as you suggested it's that it change the height and width in a wrong way. the <a> tab are in the each <li> list that are tabs. if I change the padding it lost the right size

Comment: I did not tell anything about padding.