# Including external css in Angular (4) app components

Tags: css, angular

So from [Load external css style into Angular 2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542143/load-external-css-style-into-angular-2-component) it seems that including css from an external url by putting it into the styleUrls[] worked for angular 2.  It does not work for Angular though (it just searches for the css sheet under the directory).  I can't find any documentation regarding this so I'm just hard-coding it into the entire index.html page for now.  How can I get it to work for individual components?

Edit: To clarify, by external css I mean something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css, not something included in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For including an external css (remote url)for an specific component. I've only found this way. For example for your app component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

in your app.component.scss you can import a remote url with the desired remote styles like this css file your were commenting.

```
@import url('https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css');
```

Even thought it is not a perfect solution, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was actually considering css from the web.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I've done some research and I have updated my response.

Answer (score 7):

I know it is a bit late answer, but if somebody looks for solution:
You can use command line if you use nodeJS in your app folder write:

```
npm install --save w3-css
```

You should adjust then `angular-cli.json` in your `src` folder of your app and where you register styles type following:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/w3-css/w3.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```