# Cannot load css from assets in component

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to Angular 6 and trying to use my css files in a particular component.

My angular.json file says this:

```json
"angapp": {
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  ....
```

My css files are placed under src/assets/css directory.
I have a component named **dashboard.component.ts** in

```
src/app/components/secure/dasbhoard
```

I am trying to include file **src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css** in following ways but could not:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css']
})
```

or

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['/src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css']
})
```

or

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css']
})
```

or

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
```

and tried to import css in dashboard.component.css

```
@import '/src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css';
```

None of the above is working. I get the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css'
```

The file does exist in: ..../src/app/components/secure/dashboard

I think I am missing path from the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolute path in `styleUrls` is not trivial, as documented [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4974#issuecomment-407630605).

You can still use relative path though : `../../../etc`.

Going with `@import` in your scss is another solution indeed, and you can just use:

```
@import 'src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css';
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer in this thread:

[Angular 6 - How to apply external css stylesheet (leaflet) at component level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027083/angular-6-how-to-apply-external-css-stylesheet-leaflet-at-component-level)

Imported css like this:

<strike>@import url('src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css');</strike>

url() is not required, the actual statement should be:

```
@import 'src/assets/css/sidebar-nav.min.css';
```

Comment: I don't think it is required. I don't use `url()` in my project and it works well.

Comment: Yes, thanks Mic, url is not necessary, but looks like styles are not being applied :(

Comment: Seems weird. Try doing syntax error in the css and see what happens in the browser and compiler. Also, look for styles in the browser to see where they appear. They are most likely there, but maybe something in the HTML prevents them from being applied.