# Angular 6 component doesn't get parent styles

Tags: angular, angular6

UPD:
I wrote small code for example. How I can use all styles? I have errors if use that in .scss file for child component - import "~styles.scss";
It's meaning if we use bootstrap in project, then we can't use col-lg in child component, but it's work fine in parent - For example.

I have simple structere of my parent component:

Styles.scss ( in global folder )

```
.row {
background-color: black
}
```

Parent.html

```
<content></content>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Child.html

```
<div class="row"></div>
```

So in my child I have not black background, but I have it in parent, what's wrong?

Comment: I tried making with your explanation here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-menwrr but it is working fine.. Can you recheck it??

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.row {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
::ng-deep .row {
   background-color: black
 }
```

Comment: sorry, I wrote small code for example. How I can use all styles? 
I have errors if use that in .scss file for child component - 
import "~styles.scss";

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
:host ::ng-deep .row {
   background-color: black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To add the in the index page in the app. this is reflex the change

Index.html

.row {
background-color: black !important
}

Answer (score 0):

To define styles globally add them to `angular.json` file into `styles` property.

```
...
"assets": ["src/assets", "src/favicon.ico"],
"styles": ["src/Styles.scss"]
...
```

Or follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34963135/3984210) if don't want use them as global

Comment: so I want, and it's work fine with the structure like
<parent>
<parent1>
<parent2>
But its goes fall here with <child></child>
</></</></>