# Custom Styling on <ng-content> in angular2 not working ?

Tags: angular

I am trying to style `<ng-content>` using inline css but seems style does't work on ng-content, i have to do something else for styling ?

```
<ng-content class="red"></ng-content> <p class="red">hello</p>
```

here class red works on `p` but not on

<kbd>[Working Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/srE5pcQS3nJIKJFSxto4?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`::content` is ignored.

This comes closes

You can use the `::content` selector

```
styles: ['.red {color:red} :host >>> upper {color:green}']
```

or

```
styles: ['.red {color:red} :host >>> * {color:green}']
```

> And if there are fellow LESS users, seems that LESS compiler dislikes
>   `>>>` syntax, so you need to add an alias for that, eg. `@deep: ~">>>";` and then use that like `@{deep} { /* your deep styles here */ }`

See also this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7400#issuecomment-246922468

<strike>You can use the `::content` selector</strike>

```
styles: ['.red {color:red} ::content >>> upper {color:green}']
```

or

```
styles: ['.red {color:red} ::content >>> * {color:green}']
```

According to the web components spec `::content` should be enough and `>>>` should not be required but the styles were not applied without it.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/T5CoP5qmd4nzIPAFjLNQ?p=preview)

Comment: waoo great, but what if i have multiple `ng-content` i mean named `ng-contents` than how can i apply style to them ? can you please provide any link where i can read about this `::content` and `>>>` ?

Comment: I explained a bit in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component/36175093#36175093 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542143/load-external-css-style-into-angular-2-component/34963135#34963135. Angular emulates the shadow DOM selectors with a few limitations.

Comment: I guess you need to wrap `<ng-content>` like `<div class="wrapper1"><ng-content></ng-content></div>` and then use it like `.wrapper1 ::content >>> upper`.

Comment: is there any way to know wether the content is there or not ina component?

Comment: @MukulJayaprakash something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718456/in-angular2-how-can-i-detect-is-there-any-ng-content

Answer (score 4):

In fact, it's because  is replaced by the input content. The element doesn't exist in the in-memory DOM.

Regarding your sample, when using `upper`:

```
<upper>Some text</upper>
```

that has the following template:

```
<ng-content class="red"></ng-content> <p class="red">hello</p>
```

You will have this in the DOM:

```
<upper _nghost-dks-2="">
  Some text <p _ngcontent-dks-2="" class="red">hello</p>
</upper>
```

For this reason, you can't use `class="red"` on `ng-content`.

Comment: so how can i style `ng-content` ?

Comment: You can't ;-) but you style elements in it... For example: `<upper><p class="red">Some text</p></upper>`

Comment: already tried this but not suitable as per my requirement. btw thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the ng-content and use css to select inside it?

```
<div class="red"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

CSS:

```
.red > * {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Scoped component CSS does not work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your css into the parent css file: `app/src/style.css`

**NOT** into your component's styleUrls's css file (which you included inside the component like this `styleUrls: ['design.css']`)