# Angular2 final release no longer supports :host ::shadow

Tags: css, angular, web-component, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I upgraded to Angular2 final release this morning and noticed that the CSS styles I was using in previous release candidates are no longer working.  I need to control the look a HTML element wihtin a child component from the parent.

Here's my HTML:

```
   <div id="intro">
        <stm-video [video]="PageData.WelcomeVideo"></stm-video>
    </div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
:host ::shadow 
{
    stm-video
    {
        .video-container 
        {
            height: 80vh;
            width: inherit;
        }
    }
}
```

.video-container is a HTML element inside .  I want to set the height of video-container when it's loaded in parent page.  This used to work in Angular2 RC 4 and 5.  Stopped working today after installing Angular2 final release.

Is there a more appropriate way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:host` is still supported. 
`::shadow` is not supported. As far as I know it never was.
`::content` is ignored.
`/deep/` and `>>>` are equivalent and are both still supported.

```
:host >>> {
  stm-video {
    ...
```

should do what you want.

See also [Custom Styling on <ng-content> in angular2 not working ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763252/custom-styling-on-ng-content-in-angular2-not-working/37764548#37764548)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Gunter and Clint.  With your suggestions, here is what I arrived at for solving this problem (using LESS to generate CSS):

```
@deep:  ~">>>";

:host
{
    stm-video
    {
        @{deep} 
        {
            .video-container 
            {
                height: 80vh;
                width: inherit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

having @{deep} directly under :host affects all child nodes, but putting it inside the child element just affects the styles within that child node (stm-video).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for here is `/deep/`. It applies the styles down through child components. In your parent styles you would have.

```
/deep/ .video-container 
{
    height: 80vh;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: is :host no longer supported with Angular2 final release?  /deep/ doesnt seem to work with LESS though

Comment: @TomSchreck Host should still work. You may need to use `:host /deep/` instead, I wasn't sure of the element structure by the wording of your post. Is `/deep/` removed from the css?