# Cannot Understand the Use of :host in components in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

What i have understood of host is that if i have a child component inside a parent component and we want to style a child component from the parent component we can use :host .
and :host-context for vice-versa.
Please let me know if this is the right use of host .

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

When i try to do the same in my App it dosent work

App component template

```
  <div class ="top">
    <h1>
      Home Component
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <app-ngrx></app-ngrx>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div>
```

ngrx component template

```
  <h3 class="mine">NGRX</h3>

<button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
<div>Current Count: {{ counter | async }}</div>
<button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>

<button (click)="reset()">Reset Counter</button>
```

App component CSS

```
:host(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

This do not Seem to work Please help i am not able to understand.

I looked at this question But just not able to figure out

[Angular 2: How to style host element of the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component)

Updated after @Gunter Answer

In my app-ngrx template i have added

```
  <h3 class = "mine">NGRX</h3>

<button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
<div>Current Count: {{ counter | async }}</div>
<button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>

<button (click)="reset()">Reset Counter</button>
```

and in the app-ngrx css file i have added

```
:host(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

But even without adding mine in app component like

```
<app-ngrx></app-ngrx>
```

The h3 is red where as i feel it should be red when  `<app-ngrx class = "mine"></app-ngrx>`

Comment: I don't understand your update. `<h3>` won't be affected. The whole `<app-ngrx class="mine">` should be `red`. (`<app-ngrx class = "red"></app-ngrx>` should not be red, because `red` is the wrong class - you probably meant to use `class="mine"`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ya class mine , i only want the h3 of the component to be red instead of the whole template to be shown red

Comment: Then don't use `:host`

Comment: if i just want the h3 of the ngrx to be updated from the parent not the whole template as people will want to change button color or add some class based on some value of the parent component class

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer without host how we acheive this from parent component i am so confused now

Comment: No, without `:host` you select the content of the current component. Of course if you have `<my-child>` in the template of the component and you add style `my-child { color: red; }` then seen from `<my-child>` it's styled from the parent, but if you see it from the component where you add the style, then you style its content.

Comment: So in order to style only h3 of child component we have to do that in the child component css right we cannot from the parent component css

Comment: If you want to style `<h3>` **inside** a child component you use `:host /deep/ h3 {color: red;}`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What i have understood of host is that if i have a child component
>   inside a parent component and we want to style a child component from
>   the parent component we can use :host . and :host-context for
>   vice-versa

No, this is not what it used for.

`:host` selector comes from [shadow DOM spec](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom).

> ...This scoped subtree is called a shadow tree. The element it's
>   attached to is its shadow host.

In angular world, a component's template is a shadow tree. The component's element is a shadow host. So when you're defining styles for `:host` selector, the styles are applied to the component's element.

**:host**

In your example, if you defined styles in `my-app` component, the styles will be applied to `<my-app>` DOM element. This particular configuration:

```
:host(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

Will be applied to the host element that has `.mine` class:

```
<my-app class="active">
```

If you defined styles in `app-ngrx` component, the styles will be applied to `<app-ngrx>` DOM element, **NOT** `<my-app>`. This particular configuration:

```
:host(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

Will be applied to the host element that has `.mine` class:

```
<app-ngrx class="active">
```

**:host-context**

Now, `:host-context` is also applied to the host element, but the function (parenthesis) takes a selector that is checked not against the host element itself, but against all ancestors up to document root. If such element is found, the styles are applied.

For example, this selector

```
:host(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

matches such structure:

```
<my-app class="mine">
```

whereas, this selector:

```
:host-context(.mine){
  color:red;
}
```

matches this structure:

```
<div class="mine">
 ...
   <my-app>
```

This is useful, if you want to apply styles to components view (shadow root) conditionally. This makes `h2` always bold:

```
h2 {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

whereas this

```
:host-context(.make-inner-components-bold) h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

makes them bold only if your component is inside an element with class `.make-inner-components-bold`.

Answer (score 21):

- `:host { ... }` selects the component itself
- `:host(.mine) { ... }` selects the component itself when it has `class="mine"` set
- `:host-context(.mine) { ... }` selects the component itself when one of its ancestors has `class="mine"` set

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'h3', 
  styles: [':host(.mine) { color: red; }], 
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'}) 
class MyH3Component{}
```

```
<h3 class="mine">this is red</h3>
<h3>this is black</h3>
```

or with `:host-context`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'h3', 
  styles: [':host-context(.mine) { color: red; }], 
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'}) 
class MyH3Component{}

<body class="mine">
  <my-app><my-app>
<body>
```

*AppComponent*

```
template: '<h3>this is red</h3>'
```

or with `class="mine"` set

```
<body>
  <my-app><my-app>
<body>
```

*AppComponent*

```
template: '<h3>this is black</h3>'
```

**update**

If you want to style the **content** of a child component (instead of the child component itself) you can use `/deep/`

```
:host child /deep/ h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

**update 2**
`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

Comment: So it is like not to modify css but just to select the component based on that selector

Comment: so if i remove class mine from ngrx template it wont be selected , i am really confused with this concept

Comment: If you had a component with `@Component({selector: 'h3', styles: [':host(.mine) { color: red; }], template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'}) class MyH3Component{}`, then adding or removing `class="mine"` from `<h3>` will switch the color of `<h3>` between `red` or `default`.

Comment: then adding and removing a class from a different component right ?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment.

Comment: you mentioned right then adding or removing class ="mine" from h3 how do we acheive that from the main  app component, i guess i am asking a lot but if you can provide a plunker it will be great

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: Yup thanks but this can be acheived by using normal ement selector like h3{color:red}

Comment: But for this you need to add the style to the parent component. If you want your component to style itself from the inside, you need `:host()` or `:host-context()` - In my example I made `<h3>` an Angular component, because you added `class="mine"` to this element.

Comment: Yes now i get it , if i want to target a particular element in that component how do we acheive that beacuse as of now all the elements have color red

Comment: Sorry, forgot to edit the last example where `<body>` doesn't have `class="mine"`. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: i am refer to like if my components have multiple elements i only want to add style to a particular element using host how to do that

Comment: Then you don't need `:host`. You can just use `styles: ['div.mine { color: red; }'], template: '<div class="mine">this is red</div><div>this is black</div>'`

Comment: You can use host as parent selector like `:host > div.mine` to only select `<div class="mine">` which are top-level elements inside the component.

Comment: i have updated the question a bit please check after @Gunter answer in the question, i am really confused sorry

Comment: @INFOSYS, did you get a chance to see my answer? Is your question still about two components or is it about one component?

Comment: @Maximus i did see your answer and it cleared the misconception about host and host context thanks,

Comment: @INFOSYS, so do you still have a question?

Comment: @Maximus Yes a last doubt what is the difference between host and host-context as now when i am trying examples both see, to do the same thing

Comment: @INFOSYS, I've updated my answer. Check if it's clear now

Comment: @Maximus yes thanks great this is i just figured out in the angular docs

Comment: @INFOSYS, sure, you're welcome. Yeah, this is sometimes a dilemma for me as well which answer to accept :).