# Angular 4. What is :host in angular CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, styles

I have trouble understand the concept of :host selector in Angular CSS. What exactly does it do?

I looked at here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles. It starts talking "host element" and "parent component" which are equally confusing since I can't find a concrete definition online. What exactly is host element? What makes a component a parent component?

Then there is an example of :host on this blog:
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-component-styles-host-host-context-deep-selector-example
But it looks like :host just creates a bunch of rectangles on top of each other??

It said "The style written in :host selector in CompanyComponent will be applied in  host element in PersonComponent and so on"

But what style is applied? It just create a rectangle with :host and paste it on other template

Please I need help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583629/cannot-understand-the-use-of-host-in-components-in-angular2 this will help u

Comment: I have already looked at it. The example doesn't work and I want to know that  :host does without parameter.