# What is the use case of :host-context selector in angular

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

I've seen an angular course telling that :

> `host-context` is used to style elements inside a component, depending on some condition set outside of it.

I've searched the official documentation for it in https://angular.io

but it is not documented

can some one explain the different use cases where I can use this selector for an angular component ?

can some one explain the whole meaning of the `-context` added to host here ?

without an official documentation, does it mean that when someone give one use case, it mean that it is the only case the thing refers to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Understand the Use of :host in components in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583629/cannot-understand-the-use-of-host-in-components-in-angular2)

Comment: @HJEMAI a good explanation of :host and :host-context https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Bvy4KhIs0.

Comment: making a duplicate question some seconds after posting it, will let me go in another place to search  how i can better style my component ! even if I've already searched.

Comment: can some one explain the whole meaning of the `-context` here ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/host) might help you

Comment: :host-context documentation -> https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42583926/2545680) explains the difference between `host` and `host-context`. Here is an example of `host-context` usage. Suppose you have a component that wraps an input and this input can be used inside two different components - table and dropdown. When inside a dropdown it should occupy 50% of the width, when in table - 100%. Now if you have these two components selectors defined like this:

```
<my-dropdown>
<my-table>
```

Then the styles for the input component can be defined like this:

```
:host-context(my-dropdown) input { width: 50% }
:host-context(my-table) input { width: 100% }
```