# How to apply CSS to the elements of a component through its selector - Angular7/8

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am working on an Angular 7/8 application. I have made a custom `input` component and its selector is called `<app-input></app-input>`. This `input` has some specific stylings that I may want to change somewhere else for example, by default the `border-color` is `blue`, and in another component, I want to change its style to `red`. The problem is I am unable to access the `input` element within the `<app-input></app-input>`.

In the parent component, I am applying the styles as :

**I am Using SCSS**

```js
//Styles from parent component

app-input{
    & .an-input{
        width: 100%;
        & input{
            border-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Input `<app-input></app-input>` component code**

```js
//Template
<div class="an-input">
    <input 
        [type]="type" 
        [id]="id" 
        [name]="name" 
        (focus)="inputFocus($event)" 
        (blur)="inputBlur($event)" 
        (input)="userTyping($event)"
        class="an-input-el"
    />
    <label [for]="id">
        {{label}}
    </label>
</div>


//Styles
.an-input{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    & input, & textarea{
        padding: 15px;
        color: $an-color;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border: 2px solid $font-darker;
        border-radius: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        &.input-fly{
            border-color: $an-color;
        }
        &.input-fly-error{
            border-color: maroon;
        }
    }
    & label{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-size: 13px;
        transition: .1s;
        cursor: text;
        color: $font-darker; 
        font-size: 11px;

        &.label-fly{
            padding: 0px;
            color: $an-color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file), this may help you.

Comment: You can use ::ng-deep to access descendants, however soon it will be removed. However, you can declare a `host-context()` inside your child styles to apply some styles when the parent is what in host-context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071237/what-is-the-use-case-of-host-context-selector-in-angular

Comment: @Sergey See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles. ::ng-deep is depricated

Comment: @Saksham deprecated but not removed so still can be used. Please note, that I've also noticed that in my comment and suggested an alternative to that.

Comment: @Sergey I used that, but that doesn't go that deep.

Comment: @Sergey alternative is the solution I posted

Comment: @Saksham I don't think so. Looks kind of weird

Comment: @Saksham 1) you didn't show what you got in the end. 2) it should be like `host ::ng-deep any-component you want to style`

Comment: @Saksham read about `host-context` in Angular and you will understand how you can make different styles from children depending on the parent it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angular approach would be to pass the styles as an input property to your custom input as

```
@Input() styles: any;
```

and bind it to the `ngStyle` property as

```
[styles]="styles"
```

Demo at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngstyle-as-input-property

**PS**: As one of the user mentioned to use `::ng-deep`, it is not advised to do so and will soon be depricated. More info [HERE](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: I think I should use this approach it is handier but a headache, though I would be required to pass different styles for each element.

Comment: Although this works, I don't think this is the best approach since you'd have to use this logic every time you want to apply a style to an element.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the wrong syntax in the SCSS, the amperstand (&) is used when you want to select an element that has both selectors, when you do this:

```
app-input{
    & .an-input{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

you're selecting all the elements of type `app-input` **that also have** the `.an-input` class, not the `app-input` child elements that have the `.an-input` class.

So, remove the `&` :

```
app-input{
    .an-input{
        width: 100%;
        input{
            border-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Comment: The styles still doesn't get applied !