# Angular 2+: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have my pollyfills in and I'm getting this error from Internet Explorer 11 in my main.bundle.js. It's on line 9692, but looking at the compiled code, I'm not able to make any sense of it. Here it is:

```
    styles: ["\nng-select-custom >>> .caret {\n  /* display: none; */\n}\nng-select-custom >>> .ui-select-match-text {\n  white-space: normal;\n  line-height: 21px;\n}\nng-select-custom >>> .ui-select-toggle {\n  overflow: hidden;\n}\n"]
```

Is this a common issue for Angular 2+? I'm not seeing any posts about this with NG2+.

Update: Here's a little more context for the code in question:

```
DropdownRuleInputComponent = __decorate([
    __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Component"])({
        selector: 'dropdown-rule-input',
        template: "\n  <ng-select-custom\n    [class.invalid]=\"invalidShowing\"\n    [items]=\"items\"\n    [active]=\"activeSelection\"\n    (selected)=\"selection = $event\"\n    placeholder=\"Click for options\">\n  </ng-select-custom>\n  ",
        styles: [__webpack_require__("../../../../../../pushgraph-client/lib/search/rule-inputs/default-styles.sass")],
        styles: ["\nng-select-custom >>> .caret {\n  /* display: none; */\n}\nng-select-custom >>> .ui-select-match-text {\n  white-space: normal;\n  line-height: 21px;\n}\nng-select-custom >>> .ui-select-toggle {\n  overflow: hidden;\n}\n"]
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [typeof (_d = typeof __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__shared_search_service__["a" /* SearchService */] !== "undefined" && __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__shared_search_service__["a" /* SearchService */]) === "function" && _d || Object])
], DropdownRuleInputComponent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, it still exists in Angular.

### Reason of error

```
SyntaxError: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode
```

The reason is: you've added both `styleUrls` and `styles` to one component.
You can clearly see them in your pasted webpack bundle code, that `styles` property is created 2 times.

Strange thing is that only IE 11 has a problem with it :)

---

## Solution

Rearange your styles and remove `styles` or `styleUrls`. Leave only one of them.

### Example of component broken in IE11

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  // with both `styleUrls` and `styles` IE11 crashes
  styles: [`
    h2 {
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

### Environment to reproduce

I've checked it on fresh Angular version, and it's still a problem:

```
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: Cool!... This was so long ago, I don't remember how we got around it. Probably figured out a workaround. Did you verify that IE11 does output the same error? Anything on Github about this issue?

Comment: ...Ok, now I vaguely remember figuring this out. I went back in the git history, and see where we fixed it. Pretty sure I didn't answer the question here because we were under such a mad push to get the project out. Thanks for answering the question!

Comment: Yes - I was fighting this issue yesterday while adding IE11 support for our application :) Good point - I'll paste the error, for better discoverability.

Answer (score 0):

I belive its complaining about this `ng-select-custom >>>`. My syntax has `host: >>>` instead. Not too sure missing `host` variable causing this issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax at all, or how to alter the output from Webpack/Angular-CLI.

Comment: These two links explain this more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/ Could you also grive us bit more code than just one line so we can understand it.

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: How does this code get compiled. Because I never seen anything adding `\n` and `\` before?