# How to css style angular2's Ng2-completer plugin input box and dropdown color?

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular2/4's Ng2-Completer plugin and am having trouble with styling of the component. I want to change the background dropdown to "red" and the input box to be blue.

The following is my plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/sVnfpBiEb5jBdtul4ls9?p=preview

I tried to include the following CSS, but it does not appear to impact anything:

```
    .completer-row {
        display: inherit;
        background:blue;
    }

    .completer-selected-row {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: yellow;
    }

    .completer-row p {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(50%);
    }

    .completer-dropdown-holder {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
    }

    .customid {
    background:blue;
    }
```

My component:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { CompleterService, CompleterData } from 'ng2-completer';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css'
  ],
      template: `<h1>Search color</h1>
                <ng2-completer id="customid" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="searchData" [minSearchLength]="0" [clearSelected]="true" (selected)="onSelected($event)"></ng2-completer>
                <p>Selected: {{selectedColor}}</p>
                `
    })
    export class AppComponent { 
      protected searchStr: string;
      protected dataService: CompleterData;
      protected selectedColor: string;
      protected searchData = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black'];

      protected onSelected(item: CompleterItem) {
        this.selectedColor = item? item.title: "";
      }
    }
```

Comment: input[type="search"]{ background : blue } works for me ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2 have a safety feature where  CSS only work on HTML files of their respected component. Or css have to go in the global `styles.css` file for global use. However you can force CSS to apply by adding `hots: >>> .class-name` this method will force the css to apply to a child component.
More info on this thread [Angular 2: How to style host element of the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component)
https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

Comment: Could you show me an example of this using the ng2-completer I am trying to use what you've described with a combination of wrapping the classes in :hosts(.classname) and /deep/ .classname, but here appears to be no effect.

Comment: Try `host: >>> .completer-row {
        display: inherit;
        background:blue;
    }` this seen to work when I did a similar thing. Make sure there are no space between angle brackets. If you are using IDE like intelliJ it tend to space them on formatting.

Comment: youc an see an example in `ng2-completer` [demo](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/blob/master/demo/native-cmp.css#L28)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `inputClass` propery of `ng2-completer`.
For example with bootstrap:

```
<ng2-completer [inputClass]="'form-control form-control-inline'" ...></ng2-completer>
```

Comment: Great and clear answer but Why single quotes inside double quotes? and where I can find documentation for ng2-completer?

Comment: @Nofel brackets expect an expression, so in this case we need a string, that's why we have single quotes inside double quotes. See [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview). ng2-completer documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer).

Answer (score 1):

You can style the angular ng2 completer like this:

```
::ng-deep .completer-row{

        }
```