# Set font size of Angular Material Tooltip

Tags: css, angular, tooltip, angular-material, angular-material2

I am very new to web development, and I cannot figure out how to solve the following issue, although it may be very easy.

I am using Angular 4 and Angular Material to implement tooltips like this:

```
<div mdTooltip="tooltip text" mdTooltipPosition="above">
  <span>Show tooltip</span>
</div>
```

I would like to make the font size of the tooltip text bigger. However, I did not manage to find how to do this in the Angular Material documentation, neither searching in the web. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ploppy because sometimes big companies make bad decisions. The default font size is barely legible on a standard resolution screen. PS. look up guideline in the dictionary - what you see might surprise you ;-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I know what it means, what I meant was, why use Material Design if you don't want to actually use it? I see so many people who want to modify things completely in angular material, such as trying to redesign completely the material inputs and it makes no sens at all.

Comment: @Ploppy I don't think increasing the font size by one pixel means you're not using Material Design anymore

Comment: @Ploppy probably this guy's boss. So what would be the cutoff pixel size increase to still be considered Material Design? Asking for a friend.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I stopped at 'probably', we're not here to argue on guesses.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can fix this by adding a `.mat-tooltip` css declaration in you main styles file and change the font size there. You need to set `!important` on the font size otherwise it won't show up.

Comment: Thanks but it worked for me without setting !important.

Comment: @hamidreza Can you please explain why css change in component css doens't work while if we add this into global works?

Comment: @NikhilKumarvats Sorry! I can't.

Comment: @NikhilKumarvats  you might need to consider overriding it with ng-deep

Comment: This does not work as of 15.11.2020. All i did was add the tree lines T. Bulford also added :(

Comment: minus 1 for !important.

Comment: Worked without `!important`

Comment: @NikhilKumarvats because Angular encapsulates CSS styles for individual components (it add some component id to each class defined in its css file)  so they don't affect other components. The styling for material components is defined on global level and therefore must be overriden on the same level 
see https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Answer (score 57):

Per the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api

And the spec: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.spec.ts

You can set the property 'matTooltipClass', as follows:

```
<div matTooltip="tooltip text" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="tooltip">
  <span>Show tooltip</span>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS (global - not for the component):

```
  .mat-tooltip.tooltip {
    background-color: darkblue;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
```

Also see their demo here: https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/tooltip

Also keep in mind if you are using SASS, that the container for the tooltip is at the bottom and nowhere near where you are placing it in your component's HTML, so do not nest it in that component.  Make sure it is standalone, otherwise it will not work.  This note applies as well obviously to the comment above if you just choose to override .mat-tooltip

To see the changes, in developer tools, find the div at the bottom with the class "cdk-overlay-container".  Then hover over the element. You can use your arrow keys to navigate into the element while you are hovered over to confirm whether your class is being added.

Comment: If you use `.mat-tooltip.largerTooltip` in the css definition then you don't need to put `!important`. I updated the code.

Comment: hmm, in our jhispter app, in the global, I kind of used the same approach but different in css hierarchy what your doing here... I had `.largerToolTip` followed by `.mat-tooltip` and it is working well atleast today September of 2020.

Answer (score 16):

You can use css `/deep/` selector. 
For example:

```
/deep/ .mat-tooltip {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Then you do not have to use `!important`

Comment: Can you add **:host**  to the beginning of the line?
**:host /deep/ .mat-tooltip {...}**
I think, this can help you. Good luck!

Comment: @GLR - depending on Angular version you may need to use ::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  font-size: 14px;
}

Comment: @GLR You can read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component
I hope, this help you to understand how it work.

Comment: +1. Besides allowing to avoid !important, is also works if specified within the component css rather than global css.

Comment: deep is deprecated

Comment: @IdanYadgar with deep being deprecated, what should you use instead?

Answer (score 14):

Add `ng-deep` before class name

Try this

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    background: red!important;
}
```

Comment: @GilEpshtain That's the only thing that worked for me out of all the solutions here

Comment: Worked for me in Angular v7.

Answer (score 8):

In v15, you can change css variables (in styles.scss)

```
body{
  .mat-mdc-tooltip{
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-container-color: #616161;
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-color: white;
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-font: Roboto, sans-serif;
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-size: 12px;
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-weight: 400;
    --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-tracking: 0.0333333333em;
    line-height: 12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: for me this answer works only with ::ng-deep which is recommended not to be used

Comment: use this in styles.scss

Comment: the cleanest solution

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that using a globally defined css class-name such as .customname-toolip for matTooltipClass was NOT working. My solution below, and the !important was needed; set in the global styles.css file:

```css
.mat-tooltip {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add following code in your styles.css to increase its font size i.e. 12px

CSS

```
.mat-tooltip {
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

and use **matTooltip** in your tag's as.

```
<p matTooltip="My Tooltip">...<p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way. It should work.

**test.component.html**

```
<div mdTooltip="tooltip text" mdTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipClass="myTest-tooltip">
  <span>Show tooltip</span>
</div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  /*
  styles: [`
   .myTest-tooltip {
      min-width: 300px;
      background-color: #FC5558;
      font-size: 16px;
   }
`]*/
})
```

**test.component.scss**

```
.myTest-tooltip {
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: #FC5558;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `matTooltipClass` to apply your custom class on tooltips

```
<button mat-raised-button
            matTooltip="Adding a class to the tooltip container"
            matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip">
      Custom tooltip
</button>
```

Add your style in your component style.scss file

```
.custom-tooltip {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom style only for your component by adding a custom class + using `/deep/`, which will apply the css changes **only** for your custom class and **not** globally.

for example adding a custom tooltip for an image tag :

```
<img
   matTooltip="text"
   matTooltipClass="my-custom-class"<----
   src=""/>
```

and in the css file :

```
/deep/ .mat-tooltip.my-custom-class {<---
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions ( I'm using v15), using the specific class declaration (in the html markup) is just a lot of repetition & duplication.

I wanted a global way.

```
.mat-mdc-tooltip {
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-container-color: #fff;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-font: "Baloo 2", sans-serif;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-size: 14px;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-weight: 100;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-color: #000;
 }

 .mdc-tooltip__surface {
   letter-spacing: -0.5px!important;
   border: 1px solid #333!important;
 }
```

This works just fine across the whole site. Actually I have it in my core SCSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an experience with angular but you may add a class or id for div. Then you may control with this class or id with css file.

```
<div  class="sth" mdTooltip="tooltip text" mdTooltipPosition="above"> <span>Show tooltip</span> </div>
```

And

```
.sth{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

in css file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only changes the font size of the text which is inside the `div` element ('Show tooltip'), but not the text of the tooltip.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have an posted issue for you I hope that helps : https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3927

Answer (score 0):

put the following into your global styling file `styles.css` or `styles.scss`

```
.mdc-tooltip__surface {
  letter-spacing: -0.5px!important;
  border: 1px solid #333!important;
  font-size: x-large!important;
  padding: 15px!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your component css (or home component css if you want to apply it globally. note that putting this in your global css file won't work, and you have to put it in the home component css to apply it globally).

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```