# How can I override the CSS on Angular 2 Materials Tooltips? (mdTooltip)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to make the font size bigger on the tooltips with Angular 2 Materials Tooltips.
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

How can this be done? For Angular 1 Materials, I see people suggesting to just add to the CSS class **.md-tooltip** but that's not used in Angular 2 Materials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set font size of Angular Material Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587532/set-font-size-of-angular-material-tooltip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `mat-tooltip` class that material2 use for the tooltip. You can override the properties. There is the actual class

```
.mat-tooltip {
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 14px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```