# adjust the full length of md-input-container in Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, input, angular-material

I need the full length of the input fields in my `md-card`. How you can see I defined the css-class `md-block` but it doesn't work as expected.

[image]

That's my source code:

```
<md-card layout-fill>
   <md-card-content>
      <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label>Test1</label>
         <input ng-model="test1" />
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label>Test2</label>
         <input ng-model="test2" />
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="md-block">
         <label>Test3</label>
         <input ng-model="test3" />
      </md-input-container>
   </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Do anyone have an idea what's the problem is?

Comment: Where is your css class defined?

Comment: @GLR that's a class defined by angular material.

Comment: You should overwrite it if you want a different aspect from the default. See how to change the font size of the tooltips of Angular Material here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587532/set-font-size-of-angular-material-tooltip

Comment: Can you set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) with your code so I can play around with it?

Comment: Your custom css is overwriting the default css behaviour of angular material. Your HTML code is correct. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/2e4s7053/3/

Answer (score -2):

```
<md-form-field class="input-fields">
    <input mdInput placeholder="New Password" #username>
</md-form-field>

.input-fields {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is what I'm using right now and it works as expected

Comment: I'm using angular material with angular1. that means html and javascript not typescript. And the documentation tells, that I don't need to define a custom css class when I use the class `md-block`