# How to style recursively nested child component from parent component

Tags: css, angular

This is my parent component html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="categories">
            <div class="title">All Categories</div>
            <nested-cat [data]="data" [key]="key" (action)="onClicked($event)" class="cat-container"></nested-cat>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my child component html

```
<ul class="categorys" *ngIf="items.length">
  <li class="cat"  *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="content">
      <span class="name">{{item.name}}</span>
      <span class="action">
          <button md-icon-button><md-icon color="primary" (click)="hello('hello')">edit</md-icon></button>
          <button md-icon-button><md-icon color="warn">delete</md-icon></button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <nested-cat *ngIf="item[key].length" [key]="key" [data]="item[key]" (action)="onClicked($event)"></nested-cat>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file) links and found that `:host(selector)` and `:host-context(selector)` are used to target parent and child component. But i cannot figure out how to implement in my case.

I have used these css for parent :

```
:host ::ng-deep nested-cat{
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
  }
```

which is working fine but when i try to target the first ul element, style is applied for all ul element.

```
:host(nested-cat) ::ng-deep ul:first-of-type{
    padding:0;//this will apply to all ul 
}
```

How could i target the first child (i.e ul) of first nested-cat and set padding to 0?

**Update:**

Here is a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/fU0WLIwh9V6Euoz43hvS?p=preview

Finally this is working :

```
  :host ::ng-deep .categories>nested-cat>ul{
      padding: 0 4px;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style child components from parent component's css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527605/how-to-style-child-components-from-parent-components-css-file)

Comment: i have already linked all the links you have flagged here Mr, @Vega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector should do the trick, at least for this specific example:

```
.bg > nested-cat > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Where `>` is the immediate child selector.  It only selects matching elements that are direct children, and not any descendants further down the tree.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not working . Can you illustrate in the plnkr?

Answer (score 3):

This will solve:

```
:host ::ng-deep .content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:-40px
}
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/D1dMmqVcjwbwlF4IVruS?p=preview)