# How to style component background-color in angular 4 or 5?

Tags: css, angular, components

How to style a component in angular?
I use angular 5 and I tried this:

```
:host {
    background-color: green;
    size: 200px 200px;
}
```

And this:

```
app-root {
    background-color: green;
    size: 200px 200px;
}
```

Both approaches don't seem to work.

Comment: [Angular 2: How to style host element of the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You also need to set the `display` property to something like `block`. This can be seen in the [example](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) from the docs:

```
:host {
    background-color: green;
    size: 200px 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

The `display` property is `inline` by default (you can see this in the developer tools, etc).