# angular2 get component css from backend configuration

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

Is there a way to get component css from the Backend configuration? like liferay

I have a component and this component provides textbox for the user to enter css code. Whatever css user enters in the texbox should reflect in component.

**component html**

```
<div>
<h1>I am h1 tag<h1>
<h2>I am h2 tag<h2>
<div>
```

**Editor**
[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Editor**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one answered so answering my own question. Actually this is very simple. Just create a style tag and apply css

```
<div id="dynamicStyle">
<h1>I am h1 tag<h1>
<h2>I am h2 tag<h2>
<div>
```

**component**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  color = 'red';
  ngOnInit() {
    const css = `h2 {color: green} img {background: ${this.color}`; // we can get this css from backend also
    const head = document.getElementById('dynamicStyle');
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    head.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```